# MySQL Poor Performance with Not Exists Query

Tags: php, mysql, performance, join, exists

I have an app in production right now that makes a MySQL query to select columns in a table that do not have an associated row in another table To do so, I am currently using a MySQL exists query that appears to becoming slower and slower the more results that are added.

This is an example of the current query:

```
SELECT m.ig_media_id, m.media_promotion_id FROM media_promotions m
WHERE m.likes_received < m.likes_requested 
AND m.user_id != 19 
AND m.active = 1
AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * from media_actions m_a WHERE m_a.user_id = 19 AND m_a.ig_media_id = m.ig_media_id)
ORDER BY m.created_at ASC
LIMIT 1
```

What can I do to speed this up? It is currently running at ~3 seconds and really slowing down my application.

Comment: `SELECT *` most often is a bad idea (for (NOT) EXISTS subqueries in Mysql it does not count), then perhaps using a subquery when perhaps not necessary is another one.

Comment: Posting the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` would be helpful.

Comment: @JoshuaMartell why does it matter what the NOT EXISTS SELECT statement table is? I just do not want it to meet the WHERE requirements. And, when I do select individual columns in that select statement the query becomes even slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the subquery:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
            from media_actions m_a
            WHERE m.user_id = 19 AND m_a.ig_media_id = m.ig_media_id
           )
```

You can speed this up with an index:

```
create index idx_media_actions on media_actions(ig_media_id, user_id)
```

You can also phrase this as:

```
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
            from media_actions m_a
            WHERE m.user_id = 19 AND m_a.ig_media_id = m.ig_media_id
           )
```

However, I think MySQL is smart enough to ignore the `*` in such a subquery.

Comment: Gordon, creating an index on these columns made the world of a difference!